# How do I get the image URL from a Discord message?

Tags: javascript, twitter, discord.js

I am making a bot to take a picture someone has posted in a Discord channel and post it to Twitter.

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) {
        return;
    }

    if (message.content === 's!test') {
        message.reply('this test succeeded');
    }

    if (message.channel.id === id) {
        if (message.attachments.size > 0) {

            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
            };

            const userTweet = message.member.user.tag;

            let image = message.attachments.url;
            let status = 'Success from our member '+userTweet+'! S/O @InfinitesGroup'+image;

            const postBody = {
                'status': status
            };

            message.channel.send(askEmbed).then(function(message) {
                message.react('✅')
                    .then(message.react('❌'));

                message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 5000, errors: ['time'] })
                    .then(collected => {
                        const reaction = collected.first();

                        if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                            message.delete();
                            message.channel.send(yesEmbed);
                            console.log(userTweet);
                            // console.log('Ready to Tweet article:\n\t', postBody.status);


                            oauth.post(
                                'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json',
                                twitter_user_access_token,  // oauth_token (user access token)
                                twitter_user_secret,  // oauth_secret (user secret)
                                postBody,  // post body
                                '',  // post content type ?
                                function(err, data, res) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        console.log(err);
                                    } else {
                                        // console.log(data);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        } else {
                            message.delete
                            message.channel.send(noEmbed)
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(collected => {
                        message.delete()
                        message.channel.send(noresponseEmbed)
                    });
            })
        }
    }
});
```

When it tweets to Twitter, it posts ‘Success from our member user#0000! S/O @InfinitesGroupundefined’, where undefined is the variable of the image URL I am trying to post.

How do I get the image URL from the Discord message instead of `undefined`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I’ve edited your question so that it is clear what the question is, including making the title accurately represent your question. Please read the [tour] and [ask] for how to ask a good question. I’ve also removed the stack snippet/‘code snippet’ as they are only meant for code that can be run on a browser. Please do not use a stack snippet for code that isn't runnable and format your code use a [code block](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line of code:

```js
            let image = message.attachments.url;
```

[`Message#attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) is a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of `MessageAttachment`s. Because there is no property `url` on a Collection, `message.attachments.url` evaluates to `undefined`.

You probably want to get the first attachment's URL:

```js
let image = message.attachments.first().url;
```